# nginx default server not working

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I'm using Debian, most recent dotdeb nginx-lite.
I've read that the first `server` section found by nginx will be used as the fallback/default section used if there is no specific server section for a domain.

I deleted `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` from my installation because I use a dedicated mount `/www` for everything http related.

My `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` has these lines including other confs:

```
    include /www/conf.d/nginx/default.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /www/conf.d/nginx/*;
```

default.conf looks like:

```
server {
        server_name 0.0.0.0;
        listen 0.0.0.0:80;
        rewrite ^ http://mymaintarget.com permanent;
}
```

This does not work for me. I still get this warning:

```
Restarting nginx: nginxnginx: [warn] conflicting
server name "0.0.0.0" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

Im pretty sure there is no other server section and default.conf is the first one included /  used.

Anybody knows what's wrong or how the correct way of configuring a default server is?

**Update** full config files:

**nginx.conf:**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 8;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 10;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;


        # Default VirtualHost
        include /www/conf.d/nginx/default.conf;

        # conf.d is empty anyways
        #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

        # VirtualHosts
        include /www/conf.d/nginx/*;
}
```

**default.conf:**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        rewrite ^ http://blog.flowl.info permanent;
}
```

Comment: remove that `server_name` clause or simply add the hostname itself - not an IP address, hence the **name** ;-)

Comment: @vautee tried, it still claims the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set a default server:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    rewrite ^ http://mymaintarget.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

The default_server parameter will include any other domain, ip etc

More info [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

Comment: I get `nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /www/conf.d/nginx/default.conf:3` ... I used grep to check for files containing `default`, and got none. I don't have any other servers defined besides my /www/conf folder...

Comment: Please show us your whole configuration file, there must be a conflict somewhere

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Show also any configuration file that in into /www/conf.d/nginx/*

Comment: AHHHH LOL, I include the dafault.conf twice, first directly, and second with `/*` ...

Answer (score 1):

```
    # Default VirtualHost
    include /www/conf.d/nginx/default.conf;

    # conf.d is empty anyways
    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # VirtualHosts
    include /www/conf.d/nginx/*;
```

"default.conf" gets included, and then gets included **again** in `/www/conf.d/nginx/*`

I removed the first include, and renamed "default.conf" to "_default.conf" so the file is the first to be included in the wildcard include.